# Apply Function under Group == condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a Df as followed:

```
         position_latitude  position_longitude geohash
0                53.398940           10.069293      u1
1                53.408875           10.052669      u1
2                48.856350            9.171759      u0
3                48.856068            9.170798      u0
4                48.856350            9.171759      u0
```

What I want to do know, is receiving the nearest node to this positions, using different Shapefiles based on the Geohash.

So what I want to do, is load for ever group in Geohash (ex u1) the graph from a file and then use this graph in a function for getting the nearest node.

I could do it in a for loop, however I think there are more efficient ways of doing so.

I though of something like this:

```
df['nearestNode'] = geoSub.apply(lambda x: getDistanceToEdge(x.position_latitude,x. position_longitude,x. geohash), axis=1)
```

However, I can't figure out how to load the graph only once per group, since it will take some time to get it from the file.

what I came up with so far:

```
groupHashed = geoSub.groupby('geohash')
geoSub['distance'] = np.nan

for name, group in groupHashed:
    G = osmnx.graph.graph_from_xml('geohash/'+name+'.osm', simplify=True, retain_all=False)
    geoSub['distance'] = geoSub.apply(lambda x: getDistanceToEdge(x.position_latitude,x.position_longitude, G) if x.geohash == name, axis=1)
```

definitely seems to work, however I feel like the if condition slows it down drastically

update:
just updated:

```
geoSub['distance'] = geoSub.apply(lambda x: getDistanceToEdge(x.position_latitude,x.position_longitude, G) if x.geohash == name, axis=1)
```

to:

```
geoSub['distance'] = geoSub[geoSub['geohash'] == name].apply(lambda x: getDistanceToEdge(x.position_latitude,x.position_longitude, G), axis=1)
```

its a lot faster now. is there an even better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform`

I am stubbing `G` and `getDistanceToEdge` (as `x+y+geohash[-1]`) so show a working example

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO 
data = StringIO("""
,position_latitude,position_longitude,geohash
0,53.398940,10.069293,u1
1,53.408875,10.052669,u1
2,48.856350,9.171759,u0
3,48.856068,9.170798,u0
4,48.856350,9.171759,u0
""" )
df = pd.read_csv(data, index_col=0).fillna('')

def getDistanceToEdge(x, y, G):
  return x+y+G

def fun(pos):  
  G = int(pos.values[0][-1][-1])
  return pos.apply(lambda x: getDistanceToEdge(x[0], x[1], G))

df['pos'] = list(zip(df['position_latitude'], df['position_longitude'], df['geohash']))
df['distance'] = df.groupby(['geohash'])['pos'].transform(fun)
df = df.drop(['pos'], axis=1)

print (df)
```

Output:

```
   position_latitude  position_longitude geohash   distance
0          53.398940           10.069293      u1  64.468233
1          53.408875           10.052669      u1  64.461544
2          48.856350            9.171759      u0  58.028109
3          48.856068            9.170798      u0  58.026866
4          48.856350            9.171759      u0  58.028109
```

As you can see you can get the name of the group using `pos.values[0][-1]` inside the function `fun`. This is because we care framing the `pos` column as a tuple of (lat, log, geohash), and each `geohash` within a group after groupby is same. So with a group we can grab the `geohash` by taking the last value of the tuple (`pos`) of any row. `pos.values[0][-1]` give the last value of the tuple of the first row.

Comment: thanks a lot, will try your idea, since my latest try (geoSub['distance'] = geoSub[geoSub['geohash'] == name].apply(lambda x: getDistanceToEdge(x.position_latitude,x.position_longitude, G), axis=1)) overrides all already calculated values to nan -.-

Comment: I have a little problem interpreting how you want to define G in your example, since the Graph is depending on the name of group. So I have one Graph in my file System for each group and have to load the depending Graph in the fun function. Could you provide me with more informations how I could solve it with your example?
See:
 G = osmnx.graph.graph_from_xml('geohash/'+name+'.osm', simplify=True, retain_all=False)

Comment: Updated answer with the info